# React form value does not pass to the database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have tried to pass current time to the mongo dB using mongoose in react. Although current time is visible on textbox, the value does not pass to the database. If I hardcode the value, it properly pass to the database. How to fix it?

```
const[orderTime,setOrderTime] = useState("");

function generateTime(){
  var time = new Date();
  return time.toLocaleTimeString();
}

<input type="text" className="form-control" id="OrderTime" placeholder="Order Time" value={generateTime()} onChange={(event)=>{
        
        setOrderTime(event.target.value);
    }}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [orderTime, setOrderTime] = useState("");
  function generateTime() {
    var time = new Date();
    return time.toLocaleTimeString();
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    setOrderTime(generateTime());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
        id="OrderTime"
        placeholder="Order Time"
        value={orderTime}
        onChange={(event) => {
          setOrderTime(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```